# HQL Join Query help requested

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I have the following classes:

```
  public class A{
      private Set<B> bSet;
  }

  public class B{
     private Set<C> cSet;
     private boolean isAvailable;
  }
  public class C{}
```

The HQL is:

```
   select a from A a 
      left join fetch a.bSet 
      left join fetch b.cSet 
      where a.id = ? and  bSet.isAvailable = ?
```

The question is I can't use set in where clause. How can I process this query?

Comment: Please put an alias for the joined tables and use the alias to access them

Comment: I tried using alais but got error org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: b

Answer (score 0):

try this way I just gave alias to your queries part

```
select a from A a 
      left join fetch a.bSet b
      left join fetch b.cSet c
      where a.id = ? and  b.isAvailable = ?
```

if that not work for you try toreplace ? with :id and :isAvilable Respectively as folows

```
select a from A a 
      left join fetch a.bSet b
      left join fetch b.cSet c
      where a.id = :id and  b.isAvailable = :isAvailable
```

most likely one of the two must work for you.

Comment: I tried using the above method but got error: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: b. Any way to handle?

Comment: not sure if that will help you once i do some trick to solve this issue I remember I use b.isAvilable in (:isAvilable) may be it will work for you